# Does Euclid's Lemma generalize from primes to any integer?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

If p is prime and p|a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>, then p|a<sub>i</sub> for some i

I find it hard understanding what this lemma is saying, if p was any integer, the implication seems still valid. Thank everyone for having a look and I'd appreciate if you help me.

Here is an example in which in which this lemma is used, hope it helps:

Show that if p is prime, the only solutions of x<sup>2</sup>   ≡ 1 (mod p) are integers x such that x ≡ 1 (mod p) or x ≡ −1 (mod p).

Solution:
Suppose that x<sup>2</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p). Then p divides x<sup>2</sup> −1 = (x+1)(x−1). By the Lemma above it follows that p|(x+1) or p|(x−1), so x ≡ −1 (mod p) or x ≡ 1 (mod p)

Comment: The implication is not valid for any integer. $6 \mid 4 \times 9$, but $6$ does not divide $4$ or $9$.

Comment: If $n=j\times k$ you can have $n|ab$ by having $j|a$ and $k|b$ without have $n|a$ nor $n|b$.  In fact a trivial counter example would be if $n=j\times k$. We always have $n|n$ but we have neither $n\mid j$ nor $n\mid k$.  Or a real number example let $n =10 =2\times 5$ and lite $2|j$ and say $j = 14$ and have $5|k$ and say $k = 15$.  Then we have $10|14\cdot 15= 210$.  But we do not have $10\mid 14$ nor do we have $10\mid 15$.... The point is if $p$ is prime then we *can't* break it into pieces so it has go entirely into $a$ or entirely into $b$.  A composite number *can* be split.